# Wikipedia style list editing

Tags: php

Can anyone suggest the best method of how to use PHP to create bullet lists in the same way as wikipedia does (and StackOverflow actually) when editing pages?

User would enter the following in a form which gets saved in a database...

```
text text text
My bullet list:
* bullet 1
* bullet 2
* bullet 3
Some more text here.
```

When called on a page, convert the string to...

```
text,text,text
My bullet list:
<ul>
<li>List point one</li>
<li>List point two</li>
</ul>
Some more text here.
```

I was playing about with str_replace and can obviously easily replace a star with a html tag but how do I add the closing tag etc?

Comment: http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/

Comment: Thats in perl, and not free.

Comment: While you may have to write your own implementation in another language, I'm pretty sure it says, "Markdown is free software, available under a BSD-style open source license."

Comment: A lazy search provides [this](https://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/), and [this](http://parsedown.org/).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I was trying to keep it simple and just use plain PHP but it seems that a third party add-in might be the only way. I was thinking of some way of using str_replace to find the end of the lines for example but mayby it's not that simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use string manipulation with a little regex to accomplish this. This will replace all lines that start with * to become an unordered list.

```
$some_string = ""; // your input string goes here

$string_array = explode( "\r\n", $some_string ); //here we create an array from the string, broken up by new lines

for($i = 0; $i < count( $string_array ); $i ++) {

    if (preg_match( '/^\*/', $string_array [$i] ) == 1 && preg_match( '/^\*/', $string_array [$i-1] ) == 0 && strpos( $string_array [$i - 1], '<ul>' ) === false && strpos( $string_array [$i - 1], '<li>' ) === false)
        $string_array [$i] = "<ul>\n<li>" . preg_replace( '/^\*\s/', '', $string_array [$i] ) . '</li>';
    elseif (preg_match( '/^\*/', $string_array [$i] ) == 1)
        $string_array [$i] = '<li>' . preg_replace( '/^\*\s/', '', $string_array [$i] ) . '</li>';
    if (preg_match( '/^\*/', $string_array [$i+1] ) == 0 && strpos( $string_array [$i], '</li>' ) !== false)
        $string_array [$i] .= "\n</ul>";
}

$result = implode( "\r\n", $string_array ); //here we reconstruct the array

echo $result;
```

This is a rough example but it should give you an idea of what you can do with strings like this

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using regular expressions an example would be given

`$input = "* this is a list item"`

You can use

`preg_replace("/\*\s([a-z].*)/", "<li> $1 <li>", $input);`

To get

`<li> this is a list item </li>`

If you're curious on how to use preg_replace
http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php